# Cannot read property 'leafletElement' of undefined - React Eesri leaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-native, leaflet

I'm building a esri project in react and I am following this demo. I ran into an error that I can't find an answer to. In the demo, the leafletElement is defined but somehow isn't on my code. Here is the error:

> Cannot read property 'leafletElement' of undefined

Here is the code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import L from 'leaflet';
import * as ELG from 'esri-leaflet-geocoder';
import { Map, MapContainer, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import leafletMap from 'leaflet-map';


 class App extends React.Component {
  
    componentDidMount() {
      
      const map = this.leafletMap.leafletElement;
      const searchControl = new ELG.Geosearch().addTo(map);
      const results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);
  
      searchControl.on("results", function(data) {
        results.clearLayers();
        for (let i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
        }
      });
    }
   
  render() {
    const center = [37.7833, -122.4167];
    return (
      <MapContainer
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
        center={center}
        zoom="10"
        ref={m => {
          this.leafletMap = m;
        }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution="&copy; <a href='https://osm.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
          url={"http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"}
        />
        <div className="pointer" />
      </MapContainer>
    );
  }
}

  




const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});


export default App;
```

Comment: Which version of react-leaflet package are you using, and on which example do you base your code on? Furthermore, I am not sure it can work as is in react-native.

Comment: @ghybs I am using react-leaflet v- 3.0.5

Comment: @gybs the example is https://codesandbox.io/s/2wy7v2orwr

Answer (score 0):

This [lybrary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-map) has apparently not been updated for 6 years, if you want to implement a map you should use [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps) which is recommended by react native.

Comment: While it is true that OP imports a "leaflet-map" package, they are not using it, but using the "react-leaflet" package instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using react-leaflet v- 3.0.5

But:

> the example is [codesandbox.io/s/2wy7v2orwr](https://codesandbox.io/s/2wy7v2orwr)

That example uses react-leaflet version 2.2.1

[image: dependencies list of linked code sandbox]

The API of React Leaflet wrapper highly changed between its 2 and 3 major versions.

https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v300-2020-10-31

> v3 is a full rewrite of React Leaflet and contains breaking change from v2.

The simplest solution for your case would simply be to downgrade the version of react-leaflet package in your project to better match with your example.

Or read through the documentation of the new version and adapt your code accordingly. In your case, since you want a handle to the Leaflet map instance, you would use the [`useMap` hook](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map#usemap):

```
function MyComponent() {
  const map = useMap()
  console.log('map center:', map.getCenter())
  return null
}

function MyMapComponent() {
  return (
    <MapContainer center={[50.5, 30.5]} zoom={13}>
      <MyComponent />
    </MapContainer>
  )
}
```

All that being said, as already mentioned, I am not sure it can work as is in react-native.